# Git: How to copy all files ever deleted to a certain directory?

Tags: windows, git, restore

I want to get all the files that were ever deleted, and copy them to a different directory `X`.

I got a list of all the files deleted by doing `git log --all --pretty=format:" " --name-only | sort -u`, but that was as far as I could manage.

Note:

- I don't want to make any changes to my working copy. I want to recover the deleted files to a directory `X`, `X` is at a completely different location from my repo.
- The files I wish to restore were commited, deleted, and the delete was committed. So git has them backed up.
- If it helps, I am trying to find an image that I once added. I neither have the file name, nor the commit in which I added/deleted it. So my plan is to restore all deleted files to a different directory and then go through the images manually (~50 of them).
- I am a newbie, using Git on windows.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To find deleted files: `git log --diff-filter=D --summary`. Parse output of that to grab `commitId` and file name and then get that version of the file from `commitId^` and copy to dir (`git show hash^:fileName >copyOfFileName`) and file named copyOfFileName will have your file contents. Use the full path for your fileName show in the git log.

Comment: I'm glad that you responded. The problem is, I already know what to do, but I don't know how to do it. I would be grateful if you could give me the commands too.

Comment: The commands are right there in the response. Have you even tried to type them in (git log --diff-filter=D --summary  and git show hash^:fileName)?

Comment: This is what I tried: (too long to post here. http://markdownshare.com/view/795d4e3a-4849-4761-86b5-becf21a32778)

I apologize if I misunderstood you. Could you please give me some more details?

Comment: Can you try with full file name path, anki/MainProfile/collection.media/latex-0eb5db190634622e42db3df19c9b05a1fb9a780d.png?

Comment: I already did, didn't I? (tried both the filename and relative-pathname).

I just also tried the full pathname, and got the same error.

Comment: Well, just do a "git checkout hash^" of each one that showed a deleted file and you should get the state of the whole directory just before the file was deleted and grab the file.